# How to change the visibility of the button got by Xpath in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, selenium-webdriver

Hello I am working in Selenium Automation testing with Nunit. I have one grid which have bulk of users and there is one remove button on each row of the grid. But that Remove button is visible only on mouse hover. So when I run the script, It gives me the error -

```
Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

The Xpath of button is

> "//div[1]/div[2]/div/section/div[2]/div[contains(.,'IE8 john
>   smith')]/div/div[2]/button[1]"

I tried working with the actions in selenium but still it gives me the same error.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(Driver);
            var element = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[1]/div[2]/div/section/div[2]/div[contains(.,'" + fullName + "')]/div/div[2]/button[1]"));
            actions.MoveToElement(element);
            actions.Click();
            actions.Perform();
```

Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: Are you sure the mouse has to be over that *specific* element? I would open up Chrome Developer tools, look at the markup around that element, mouse your mouse over the checkbox and see *exactly* what changes in the HTML markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to force element to be visible using JS:

```
 IWebElement element = driver.FindElement();
  js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible', arguments[0].style.height = '1px'; arguments[0].style.width = '1px'; arguments[0].style.opacity = 1", element);
  element.Click();
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the following procedure will help

1. using Actions, hover over the element step
2. insert an implicit wait till the element is visible
3. click the button