# Uploading image to <div> selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I've been trying to upload a picture to this div:

```
<div class="drop-box ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ngf-select="" ngf-drop="" ng-model="file" ngf-accept="'*'" accept="*" ngf-drag-over-class="{accept:'dragover', reject:'dragover-err', delay:100}" ngf-validate="{size: {min:'5KB', max:'512MB'}}" ngf-keep="keep" ngf-keep-distinct="keepDistinct" ngf-reset-on-click="resetOnClick" ngf-reset-model-on-click="true" ngf-stop-propagation="true" ngf-allow-dir="false" ngf-drop-available="dropAvailable">
    <i class="ti-image"></i>
    <i class="ti-video-clapper"></i>
    <p class="upload-text ng-scope" translate="">Drag and Drop an Image or Video, or Click Here to Start.</p>
    <div class="loader hidden" id="loader">
        <img src="http://cdn.gramblr.com/images/ajax-loader-upload-step1.gif">
    </div>

</div>
```

I'm trying to do it by finding the element and then try to use SendKeys with the image path:

```
upload.SendKeys(path);
```

The error it receives is: `unknown error: cannot focus element`

I'm stuck here, I don't know what is stopping me from uploading the image, I know that this method works when you are uploading a picture to a `<input>`, maybe that's why it doesn't work.

How could I upload a picture to this div?

Comment: Could you share how to find upload element??

Answer (score 0):

The error means you are basically sending keys to an element which cannot be focused and sent keys to. In other words, the `upload` does not refer to the `input` element, but should.

Find the corresponding `input` element with `type="file"` and send keys to it. The element can be hidden - in this case, you can make it visible, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18098484/771848) with a sample code.

Comment: Thats the thing, there is not input on the website to upload the picture, its on the div

Answer (score 0):

Encounter the same problem in Gramblr and solve it. Try this please:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).sendKeys(yourimage);
```

There is one hidden input type file and very unconnected to the location we need to press

Answer (score 0):

i got the same problem for uploading video on TikTok and here how i solve it.

i search on the page source with keyword <input and found this line of code just bellow the <div

```
<input type="file" name="upload-btn" accept="video/mp4,video/x-m4v,video/*" class="jsx-1828163283 upload-btn-input">
```

so, here is my complete code to upload video to tiktok

```
el = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='file']"));
el.SendKeys(uriVideo);
```

if you can share your complete html maybe i can help you find the correct input element